# How to write this table in a for loop?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

Desired output:

```
2
4 2
6 4 2
8 6 4 2
```

Here is my code:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 7; i += 2) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j += 2) 
        cout << j + 2 << " ";
    cout << endl; 
}
```

and I get a wrong answer.

Comment: Trevor Philip welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question was answered more than once, so please make sure to *accept* one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach with the double for loop was a good idea. Here is my generalized attempt, which allow to print what you want in `n` lines, rather than just 4:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n = 4;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for(int j = i; j >= 0; --j) {
            cout << 2 * (j + 1) << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2 
4 2 
6 4 2 
8 6 4 2
```

<kbd>[Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/oF1nd1wHOVHsJDMy)</kbd>

PS: This approach minimizes (if not exterminates) the usage of magic numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack overflow.
You just went the wong way around with your inner for loop

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
     for(int i = 0; i <= 7; i += 2){
       for (int j = i; j >= 0; j -= 2) {
        cout << j + 2 << " ";
        }
      cout << endl; 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

this gives you the desired output:

```
2 
4 2 
6 4 2 
8 6 4 2
```